# Ajax PHP not returning updated variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My apologies, similar questions have been asked before - Tried a lot of things and can't figure out why this is not working. I'm calling ajax via a click function. I can't seem to get the jList value to return, updating the variable in the main page.

Here is a simplified version of what is not working. PHP file:

```
<?php

echo <<<END
  <script type="text/javascript">

    jList = "ELLO!!??";
    //alert(jList);

  </script>
END;

?>
```

Main Page is this:

```
<script>
var jList = false;
...
...
...

function loadMore(listFile, nextS, nextE) {
  url = 'files/php/jList.php?l='+ listFile +'&s='+ nextS +'&e='+ nextE;

  $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'POST',
      success:function(results) {
          console.log(jList); // can't get the var to update with the value from PHP 
      }
  });

}
...
...
...
  $("#readMore").unbind("click").click(function(e){
    loadMore(listFile, nextS, nextE);
   });
</script>
```

Continually returns (console.logs) the value set initially on the main page. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: The return data from AJAX isn't executed, it's just put in the `results` variable.

Comment: If you want it to be executed, use `$.getScript`, and don't put the `<script>` tags in the return data.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the info - could you show me what that looks like in an answer - it would save me another hour of trying to figure that part out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP should be:

```
<?php
echo 'jList = "ELLO!!??";';
?>
```

And the jQuery should be:

```
$.getScript(url, function() {
    console.log(jList);
});
```